# Different behaviour under valgrind vs normal execution?

Tags: valgrind

I have a program witch is a xmpp client that connect to a server.
I use gloox library to do that.
When I run the program, it runs ok and connects to the server.

But when I run it under valgrind, the program never sends

```
<iq id='uid:4efa1893:327b23c6' type='set' from='user@server/ressource' xmlns='jabber:client'><session xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session'/></iq>
```

to the server.

Had anybody experience such problem?

Are there any parameter I specially need to run valgrind with to make sure that it is the same environement as a normal program execution?

Comment: Um... I think you misunderstand Valgrind. The purpose of that program is to break programs which have errors in them that might otherwise be missed. It sounds like it's working.

Answer (score 2):

The *very* first question is: did Valgrind report any errors in the execution of your program?

If your program is well-defined, and Valgrind didn't report any errors in it, then the program is supposed to behave exactly the same way under Valgrind as without it (only slower); no special settings required.

It is somewhat more likely that Valgrind *did* report some errors, and if so, your program is likely *not* well-defined, in which case your question is *mute* -- your program doesn't work the same because it is not well-defined (i.e. depends on undefined behavior).